# string has not been declared, QT

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to change a certain text box message. It will display my output.

This is what I have in my main()

```
#include "form2.h"
....
string recvMSG = "random";
```

182::       Form2::changeOutput(recvMSG);
    ...

within my form2.h I have:

```
#include <string.h>    
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>    
...
    void Form2::changeOutput(string s)
    {
    QString s1 = i18n(s);
    output_box.setText(s1);

    }
```

But i still get:
.ui/form2.h:56: error: ‘string’ has not been declared

Thanks.

**Edit:: kk so now its showing::
TCPClient.cpp:182: error: cannot call member function ‘virtual void Form2::changeOutput(std::string)’ without object**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`string` is in the `std` namespace, so you either need to refer to it as `std::string`, or you need to make the name available in the current scope with `using namespace std;` or `using std::string;`.

Also the header is called `string`, not `string.h`, so include it this way:

```
#include <string>
```

Generally you also might want to use QT's `QString` instead of `std::string` if you are using it in connection with QT components that usually take `QString` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use the header `<string>` and then use `std::string` (even better would be `const std::string &`)

Comment: And even better is not to mix STL and Qt string classes and containers.

Comment: True that, but sometimes you want to hide internal datatypes of a library you use in the interfaces of your classes, to avoid clients to have to include 3rd-party headers. It's all circumstatial.